# How can I rewrite the sentence in professional way?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I have a sentence. Could you help me to rewrite it more professional way? Thanks

> The advantage of these methods is that guarantee to achieve a good optimal solution, and thus these methods are insensitive to position of initialization. However, these methods ultilize matrix representation which cannot allow to handle with high noise.

Comment: You've got two sentences there, and I haven't the faintest idea what they mean.

Comment: Yes, I will explain it. First sentence, I want to said that these methods can achieve global solution, then they are not sentensitive to something. Second sentence, I want to explain the weakness of these method. It has limitation is that it use something, then the weakness is that it cannot handle with noise. That is meaning of my sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so there's a couple of issues here: the sentences themselves and the current grammatical arrangement of the words.

I have read your statements a couple of times, and suggest as follows:

The advantage of *the use of* these methods is that *they* guarantee to achieve <strike>a good</strike> *an* optimal solution<strike>, and thus</strike> *In this manner,* these methods are insensitive to *the* position of initialization.

The *insensitive to* phrase does not sit well yet, though. Could it read 'not sensitive' instead? If the sense of the message is intact with this rendering, then it may be best.

The second sentence I cannot make English sense of, sorry. The piece *which cannot allow to handle with high noise* is difficult to understand the meaning of. Cannot allow high noise, cannot handle high noise, have a low tolerance to noise - all these are related to the methods not handling noise themselves.
If the sense is that they must not be handled in a noisy environment, then the sentence would read

*However, as these methods utilize matrix representation, they must not be used where high noise is present.*

Combined, the entire piece reads:

*The advantage of the use of these methods is that they guarantee to achieve an optimal solution. In this manner, these methods are not sensitive to the position of initialization. However, as these methods utilize matrix representation, they must not be used where high noise is present.*

Does this make the sense you require? I have no idea what the methods you refer to are - products, ways of doing things, or programmatic codes referred to as methods. Nor can I ascertain the relationship between noise, initialization or position. But there is my attempt, given the information (or lack thereof).

Comment: In mathematic, it may not make sence. However, i just looking for the way to explain it

Comment: Glad to help. Can you mark as the answer, then?